# Top users by number of processes and most active

Tags: linux, shell

```
if [ -d $1 ] && [ $#2 -gt 0 ]; then
    find $1 ps aux | awk '{ print $1 }' | sed '1 d' | sort | uniq | while read line true; do  #do forever
                                                                        who $line | sort $2   #show loggerd-in users, sorted alphabetically
                                                                        sleep 10              #wait 10 seconds
                                                                    done                      #carry on 
else
     echo "The parameter is invalid"
    exit 1
fi
```

**Question** - Write a shell script which provides every 10 seconds a sorted list (in a file) with the actively logged users aside with the number of processes they own. Each minute the same script will print on the screen in alphabetical order the list of the first 10 users and their group who a) had the most processes in the last 20 seconds, b) had the most active processes from the start of the script. The number of seconds (see 10) and the number of users (see 20) should be provided as parameters in the command line

This is what I have now, I dont know if everything will work, but I am struggling with making everything work with the loops.

Comment: start from somewhere, this is very easy once you get going.

Comment: And, where is your code? We don't resolve test questions, we help you to find a solution

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's the context?  Who gave you this assignment?

Comment: "Begin at the beginning," the King said, very gravely, "and go on till you come to the end: then stop." - Lewis Carroll, Alice in Wonderland :-)

Comment: You must have been a diplomat and poet in a prior life...

Answer (score 3):

You would *start* by researching `who`, `sleep`, `while`, and `sort`. Then you would come back with a question once you've tried *something,* however bug-ridden it may be. This is not meant to be criticism, just help in the future for posting more acceptable questions.

For what it's worth, your code will probably be a variation on this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while true ; do    # do forever
    who | sort     # show logged-in users, sorted
    sleep 10       # wait a bit
done               # carry on
```

You'll obviously need to adapt it to your more specific requirements but, since you only asked for a *start,* there it is.

Some of your more complex requirements may require tools other than `who` and probably also require `awk` for text processing. You'll have to research that bit since it is, after all, *your* assignment.